# how can i set the right PATH to git bash?

Tags: javascript, database, windows, git, cmd

Okay to voice out my the problem am having. my git bash and CMD was all good. i installed MongoDB then i set a PATH for MongoDB in the environment variable (windows 10). i used *C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin* soon after that my git bash is no more responding to commands such as "node -version" .
**how can i get to  set my git and MongoDB to work perfectly**

i tried `env|grep PATH` in my git and this is what i get.

````
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
ACLOCAL_PATH=/mingw64/share/aclocal:/usr/share/aclocal
MANPATH=/mingw64/local/man:/mingw64/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man:/share/man
PATH=/c/Users/SAMSUNG/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/bin:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
INFOPATH=/usr/local/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/info:/share/info
HOMEPATH=\Users\SAMSUNG
ORIGINAL_PATH=/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/bin:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin```
````

Comment: I would expect at least all of these defaults, `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;` to be included in your . `%PATH%` variable. This certainly shows that you've been incorrectly modifying your environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
PATH=/c/Users/SAMSUNG/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/bin:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/SAMSUNG/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Do not see, that mongo is appears in this variable.
Try to edit your profiles and update PATH variable for git-bash
c:/users/USER/.profile
or
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc\profile